# Add custom non-attribute filter when elastic search is enabled

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, layered-navigation, elasticsearch

I want to add custom non-attribute filter(data is coming from custom table which has product id as foreign key) when elastic search. I have already done for MySql engine but in case of Elastic search,the aggregation data of my custom field is not coming.

Can anyone guide me to any possible solution? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom attribute to Magento elastic document

https://webkul.com/blog/add-non-product-attribute-to-magento2-elastic-documents/